# Compressing clipped raster in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I am using QGIS: Raster/Extraction/Clipper

I have a raster image (Sentinel 2 satellite 3 bands combination, total area: 1,000,000 hectares, file size 740 MB) from which I clip a certain area, which accounts to 1% of the total image.

When I save it, the size of the clipped raster is 700 MB (only 1,000 hectares),

How can I reduce the clipped file size?

Comment: What software or library are you using to save/clip it?

Comment: This seems like a problem with your processing extent. If you use the full extent of your input raster, all cells surrounding your clipped part will contain NoData values and therefore blow the size of the raster.

Comment: Is the original compressed? Is the clipped one compressed?

Comment: using QGis: Raster/Extraction/Clipper

Comment: can´t tell weather the original or the clipped are compressed or not...